# Clipboard paste issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

My application gets the string from the clipboard:

```
IDataObject dataInClipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
string stringInClipboard = (string)dataInClipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
```

Then it manipulates the data and copies the result string to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

It's supposed to have a table from the Excel worksheet as the *input clipboard* and a string separated by [\t\r\n] as the *output clipboard*.

SetText() is supposed to clear the clipboard and I really have the required output clipboard. However when I manually paste it to the same Excel worksheet the previous (input) clipboard content is pasted.

Meanwhile if I *previously close* my application the correct output string is pasted. Moreover, if I previously finish the Excel process and then start it again the correct output is pasted as well.

Where is the bug?

Comment: AFAIK The clipboard doesn't have In and Out only different formats. If you copy from Excel it will put 8? different formats from a special MSOffice format including formatting to Tab Delimited data (as text) and when you paste it will check each format in a priority order.  Get a clipboard viewer which shows ALL the formats in the clipboard and check the clipboards contents at each stage in the process. If you're still struggling I'd like to see the contents of the clipboard viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I meant that the clipboard contains a table when it is processed as the application input and it contains a string as the application output.

Comment: Use the clipboard to watch the clipboard with breakpoints set in your app, step through and check the contents is as expected after each line runs.  It might be that Excel has a preferred format on the clipboard so that `SetText` has no effect until the rest of the clipboard is cleaned up.  The clipboard can behave in different ways when an Application with an open handle to the clipboard is closed. It may be cleaning up some of the clipboard when your application closes.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot public images here; anyway the clipboard before and after the app closing stays the same. It has the same Text, DataObject, LocaleID, Ole Private Data etc.

Comment: If the same information is in the clipboard I'm surprised that different information is pasted from the clipboard. The only thing I could recommend is to explicitly call `EmptyClipboard` (WinAPI) or `Clipboard.Clear` before calling `SetText`

Comment: I've just found out there might be a correlation between my issue and the fact that Microsoft Office clipboard cannot be cleared with the Clipboard.Clear() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the problem disappears when the application window is closed. Moreover, I decided to change the program logic: if it is supposed to work only with the Excel why not to turn it into the add-in? So, thank you guys for the assistance, the problem is solved for now.